# Dynamic scale down images while maintaining proportion

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to dynamically scale down variable portrait and landscape images to fit proportionally within a browser window.

My current image resizing attempt is here: http://jsfiddle.net/6pnCH/4/

I need the image already scaled vertically when the browser loads.

At the moment i only have it started to scaling when `onBrowserResize` is fired.

Also the image seems to be stretching and warping on resize and i need to keep them proportional.

Pretty sure Javascript is the key to solve this, but my knowledge of it is fairly limited so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.slide img').css({
    maxHeight: $('.slide').height() * 0.8,
    maxWidth: $('.slide').width() * 0.8
  });
});
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#slide {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.slide {
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display: table-cell;
}

.slide:after {
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.slide img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="slide" class="slide"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pnCH/8/)

You do not need to use `Javascript` this time.

You do not want to stretch the `img` so dont use width and height applied to it, look.

Only CSS still can do the trick:

```
#slide {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.slide {
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display: table-cell;
}

.slide:after {
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.slide img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10%; //here is the trick
}
```

Comment: This stretches the images and doesn't keep the proportions. i need the image to maintain the same aspect ratio when scaled down.

Comment: i need the image to resize but i need it to keep the same proportions as it resizes so it is scaled to fit within the variable size of its div.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use css3 `background-size: cover` or `background-size:contain` ?

something like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-size:cover; background-image:url(YOUR_IMAGE.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: this tiles the image vertically and doesnt scale the image when it is too tall for the div.

Comment: try with contain then... and use background-repeat:no-repeat;

Comment: contain is making it very small in the window. Not sure css can solve this one, ive being trying with it for a while now. I imagined there was a way of using javascript to get it to resize proportionally when scaled vertically as css can only scale it horizontally.

Comment: -1 for http://www.w3schools.com reference. -- see http://www.w3fools.com for more info.

Comment: I had no idea that w3schools.com was doing that, @PauloRoberto. I removed the link.

Comment: @Jorge greetings, you left the dark side of the force, padawan.

Answer (score 0):

this illustrates perfectly what i was after and done without javascript after all!

http://codepen.io/jasonbradberry/pen/sHJhl

for anyone else after the same thing my amended code would look like this:

```
.slide img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```